# Why some projects choose the extension for source files .cc in c++?

Tags: c++

Any reason for that, what is `.cc` for?

Comment: I believe the `cc` extensions comes from the time when C++ was **C** with **C** lasses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct C++ code file extension? .cc vs .cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/correct-c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp)

Comment: @Hans: And JaredPar has the #1 answer in both questions - though I'd argue that the answer here is slightly more informative and incorporates the essence of the answer in the other question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++ is the ultimate language of choice and flexibility and C++ developers like to be different.  The .cc extension is just one of the many that people choose for header and source files.  Some others I've seen.

- No extension: Popular with header files
- .h
- .hpp
- .cpp
- .cc
- .c
- .C (explicit capital on case sensitive file systems)
- .cxx
- .inl (for inline templates)

Which to use is merely a matter of preference.  There is no inherent gain from choosing one extension over the other.

The only real effect the extension has is to kill a team's productivity for a day or two while they debate the best one to use.

Comment: Don't forget the capital-C extension (*.C) for C++, which of course will cause a bit of pain if you ever decide to move the project to a system like Windows, which doesn't see case as significant in filenames.

Comment: Though most uses have fallen by the way side of history and the most popular choice for c++ source is *.cpp (though historically some keep cropping up).

Comment: +1 for `only real effect the extension has is to kill a team's productivity for a day or two while they debate the best one to use.` =)

Comment: `.c++` is a valid extension on most filesystems, but for some reason it's rarely used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware for a deep reason for it other than that the string "c++" makes a poor extension on many OSes. :-) I believe these conventions developed before there was a standard, and because the language and compilers themselves generally don't ascribe any particular meaning to the extensions of the source files, no standard was ever necessary. `.cc` might originally have been a reference to "C with Classes," but that's speculation on my part (and maybe Joe's).

`.cc`, `.cpp`, and `.cxx` are all common extensions for C++ source files.

Comment: The compilers don't, but "make" does.  On Solaris, if you have x.cc you can type "make x" and have a chance of getting an executable (depends on, well, dependencies - you may need explicit -I, -L, -l).  FWIW, .cpp doesn't work (at least last time I checked, though I'm on Linux most of the time these days).