# Syntax for Function Prototyping in Header Files

Tags: c++, syntax, user-defined-functions, function-prototypes

Consider I have the following function prototype:

`void MyFunction(int MyParameter);`

With the following definition:

```
void MyFunction(int MyParameter)
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Where should they each be put if I have a header file (no `main` function) with a namespace?  Does the prototype go in the namespace and the definition outside it?  Or do they both go in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to have a namespace, both should be inside :

.h :

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
void MyFunction(int MyParameter);
}
```

.cpp :

```
void MyNameSpace::MyFunction(int MyParameter)
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated sidenote, why does the second file have to be a .cpp?

Comment: It does not have to be ".cpp".
It must be something recognizable by your C++ compiler.
Like .c, .cpp or .cxx for examples

Comment: Is that just for debugging purposes (seeing if there are any syntax errors), or is there another reason?

Comment: You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/correct-c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp for more informations

Answer (score 1):

If your prototype is not in the namespace, then you do not have to put the definition in the namespace. If the prototype is in a namespace, the definition should be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

They both have to be in the namespace