# How to call Linux command from C++ program?

Tags: c++

I have written the following simple C++ program in order to learn how to call Linux command(s) from C++ program (by using the system command)

Please advise why I have the errors from the C++ compiler? What is wrong with my program?

### more exm2.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  system("echo -n '1. Current Directory is '; pwd");
  system("mkdir temp");
  system();
  system();
  system("echo -n '3. Current Directory is '; pwd");
  return 0;
}


  [root@linux /tmp]# g++ -Wall  exm2.cc  -o exm2.end

  /usr/include/stdlib.h: In function גint main()ג:
  /usr/include/stdlib.h:738: error: too few arguments to function גint system(conג
  exm2.cc:7: error: at this point in file
  /usr/include/stdlib.h:738: error: too few arguments to function גint system(conג
  exm2.cc:8: error: at this point in file
```

Comment: Do you read your error messages before posting? It says the problem **right there**.

Comment: none of the things you do via system() need to be done via system. See getcwd(), mkdir() etc. system() is terribly non-portable, but neatly masks that until runtime.

Comment: I am very sorry for this but this is the first prog in C++ again sorry and thanx about your great remark

Comment: How does this have four upvotes???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `system()` without a `char*` parameter.

So these statements are **wrong**:

```
system();
system();
```

If you are not going to make anything, just don't put anything in there.

Comment: @jon- What were you intending for the line `system();` to do?  Changing it to `system("");` would get rid of the "too few arguments" error but it wouldn't necessarily make the statement useful.

Answer (score 13):

`system()` takes one argument. So, you could call it with an empty string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  system("echo -n '1. Current Directory is '; pwd");
  system("mkdir temp");
  system("");
  system("");
  system("echo -n '3. Current Directory is '; pwd");
  return 0;
}
```

However, you may as well just leave those lines out.

Answer (score 8):

the `system()` function requires a parameter.
Try removing the 7th and 8th line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  system("echo -n '1. Current Directory is '; pwd");
  system("mkdir temp");
  system("echo -n '3. Current Directory is '; pwd");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes you right , I take your remark and from now I will write the name with ".cpp" , thanx allot

Comment: @jon: No, he's not right.  A c++ source file can have any extension you want it to.  Some extensions are more common than others. ".cpp" and ".cc" are both perfectly acceptable, and both widely used.

Comment: @PigBen OK, thanks for your nice correction , it’s wonderful to get professional answers from the best developers in the world great and thanks again

Comment: @PigBen I didn't knew about `.cc` , Thanks

Comment: From one of the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1545080/10358768, *possible origin:* `cc --> C with classes` and `cpp --> C plus plus`!

Answer (score 3):

`system` takes a `const char*`. You call it 5 times, passing nothing to it twice.