# how to compile Qt code in command line on Mac OS

Tags: c++, qt, macos

I download this : http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-mac-opensource-4.7.2.dmg and install it.
Then I got a Qt helloworld.cc.

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
     hello.resize(100, 30);

     hello.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

I tried to compile it but failed. "

> ‘QApplication’ was not declared in
>   this scope "

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works here for me.  You didn't show your command line, but it seems like you aren't passing the right flags to tell your compiler where the headers/frameworks are.  Here's what I used:

```
g++ -I /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers \
    -o example example.cpp \
    -framework QtGui -framework QtCore
```

Comment: nice,Thanks bro. you save my time!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better/easier to use a one-line .pro file and "qmake; make" instead of invoking g++ directly?

Comment: If you want to do more than a quick hello world test, then the proper way to compile Qt software is to use project files and qmake.

Answer (score 4):

you can also do this (I hope I'm not wrong):

```
$ qmake -project
$ qmake
$ make
```

of course you should cd to your source file. Also, I think it's a good idea to stick to the `*.cpp` file naming when you work with Qt

Comment: qmake on MAC would create by default xproject project. have to use qmake with a switch. e.g: qmake -spec macx-g++

Comment: @koan: I'm not saying that there are problems, it's just a good idea. For me the *.cc files are associated with pure C.
@Valentin Heinitz: I have compiled Qt from sources, and it generates a makefile by default. I think it's configurable from within the .pro file - what is generated by default.

Comment: In what world are .cc files associated with pure C ? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B

Comment: @koan: you are right, that was just in my world, but here is a link on this specific topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/correct-c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp