# Xcode C++ Standard Libraries not found

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4.6.3

I've created an Allegro 5 project in Xcode 4.6.3 as an empty project. I've added all the Allegro 5 libraries as described in the Allegro documentation. But now I need to use some C/C++ libraries and get the error, that Xcode doesn't find the libraries (e.g. 'fstream file not found').

```
#include <allegro5/allegro5.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
```

How can I add the standard libraries to Xcode projects so that it finds them? Unfortunatelly I can't find any solution. This is not an Objective-C Project. It's written in C++ and also works if I don't use any of these libraries.
Thanks!

Comment: What C++ library is set in the project settings?

Comment: Where can I find these settings? Under 'Header Search Paths' are only the Allegro Paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the name of your source file end with an extension that indicates it's C++?  If it ends in (for instance) `.c` or `.m`, the compiler will not consider it to be C++, therefore the C++ headers won't be found.  Try changing the extension on the source file name to `.cpp` (or some other extension that implies C++, see [C++ code file extension? .cc vs .cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/correct-c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp) ) and see if the header is found.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. I did not consider to check the extension. It was .m and I changed it to .cpp now.

Comment: better to use .mm extension. Can compile with CPP plus Cocoa