# Run C library from Node.js

Tags: c++, c, node.js

I'm completely new to C, but have a small program (interfacing with hardware on RaspberryPi) that I'd like to be able to run from Node.js. From what I can make out in the Node.js docs, I can run a C++ program by exporting the program as a NODE_MODULE http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

I've been trying to figure out the differences between C and C++, but am unsure if I can just export the code I want to run as a C++ file (maybe by changing the file extension to .cc?) Or if there is another way to use the C code in node.js.

Also, I don't understand if I need to 'build' the C file, or if I can provide node.js with the .c file extension.

I do not want to run the C code using the Node's child process, though I know that is possible. I would much prefer to export the C code as a module, as the Node.js documents describe.

Here's the code I'm looking to run in node.js

```
    //  How to access GPIO registers from C-code on the Raspberry-Pi
//  Example program
//  15-January-2012
//  Dom and Gert
//


// Access from ARM Running Linux

#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE        0x20000000
#define GPIO_BASE                (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000) /* GPIO controller */

// WOULD I INCLUDE NODE.js HERE?? ##define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXTIMINGS 100

//#define DEBUG

#define DHT11 11
#define DHT22 22
#define AM2302 22

int readDHT(int type, int pin);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (!bcm2835_init())
        return 1;

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("usage: %s [11|22|2302] GPIOpin#\n", argv[0]);
    printf("example: %s 2302 4 - Read from an AM2302 connected to GPIO #4\n", argv[0]);
    return 2;
  }
  int type = 0;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "11") == 0) type = DHT11;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "22") == 0) type = DHT22;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "2302") == 0) type = AM2302;
  if (type == 0) {
    printf("Select 11, 22, 2302 as type!\n");
    return 3;
  }

  int dhtpin = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (dhtpin <= 0) {
    printf("Please select a valid GPIO pin #\n");
    return 3;
  }


  printf("Using pin #%d\n", dhtpin);
  readDHT(type, dhtpin);
  return 0;

} // main


int bits[250], data[100];
int bitidx = 0;

int readDHT(int type, int pin) {
  int counter = 0;
  int laststate = HIGH;
  int j=0;

  // Set GPIO pin to output
  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, HIGH);
  usleep(500000);  // 500 ms
  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, LOW);
  usleep(20000);

  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);

  data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;

  // wait for pin to drop?
  while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin) == 1) {
    usleep(1);
  }

  // read data!
  for (int i=0; i< MAXTIMINGS; i++) {
    counter = 0;
    while ( bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin) == laststate) {
    counter++;
    //nanosleep(1);     // overclocking might change this?
        if (counter == 1000)
      break;
    }
    laststate = bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin);
    if (counter == 1000) break;
    bits[bitidx++] = counter;

    if ((i>3) && (i%2 == 0)) {
      // shove each bit into the storage bytes
      data[j/8] <<= 1;
      if (counter > 200)
        data[j/8] |= 1;
      j++;
    }
  }


#ifdef DEBUG
  for (int i=3; i<bitidx; i+=2) {
    printf("bit %d: %d\n", i-3, bits[i]);
    printf("bit %d: %d (%d)\n", i-2, bits[i+1], bits[i+1] > 200);
  }
#endif

  printf("Data (%d): 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", j, data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

  if ((j >= 39) &&
      (data[4] == ((data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF)) ) {
     // yay!
     if (type == DHT11)
    printf("Temp = %d *C, Hum = %d \%\n", data[2], data[0]);
     if (type == DHT22) {
    float f, h;
    h = data[0] * 256 + data[1];
    h /= 10;

    f = (data[2] & 0x7F)* 256 + data[3];
        f /= 10.0;
        if (data[2] & 0x80)  f *= -1;
    printf("Temp =  %.1f *C, Hum = %.1f \%\n", f, h);
    }
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the filename issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/correct-c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I actually looked at that question, but wasn't sure exactly how that relates to C vs C++

Comment: C code that is also C++ code could be renamed to any extension that  gcc takes as C++ http://stackoverflow.com/a/1546107/103081 ; However, there are several differences between typical C and C++ code, beginning with the included libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're completely new to C, it might actually be less of a headache to do this all from javascript-land instead, using one of several modules on npm for interacting with GPIO (on the Pi). One such module is the [onoff](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff) module.

Comment: Thanks mscdex, I'm doing some stuff already with the wiring-pi module, but it appears these temperature sensors work quite differently than assigning and reading values from the GPIO. They are time sensitive, and apparently the best way to work with them is via C or C++.