# how is an header file implemented say an string.h file

Tags: c++, c

In c++, does string.h header file contain only the decleration of the string functions?

If true, then where are they implemeted.

Comment: search string.h in solution file (External Dependencies) you will be navigated to header file actually

Comment: I found that it contains only the decleartion of the prototypes for the needed functions

Comment: what else you need? Implementation? its implemented in string.cpp

Comment: In a `string.cpp` file which is compiled to a library `(say x)`. Now your linker links your code with `x` to allow you to use functions declared in `string.h`

Comment: So, U Mean a default string.cpp, file exists with all the needed defination implemeted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header files normally only contains prototype declarations of methods, just to satisfy initial compiler checks. The implementation files are already compiled to binary forms and distributed as library files. They are linked to your program during the linking process.

If you have studied C, you will remember that you used to add a prototype declaration of your custom method (which is defined below main() function) on top of the main() method. If not, you will get a compiler error. Header files contains these kinds of protocol declaration of methods that is defined in related cpp/c files, so that initial checks won't stop the compilation. Writing this way also helps to hide the implementation part of your software, but other users can use this method for their needs by seeing the protocol declaration.

You can get more information about the compiling linking process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264256/640731).

To answer your question

> In c++, does string.h header file contain only the decleration of the
>   string functions?

Yes, they only contain declarations

> If true, then where are they implemeted.

The related C++ files are compiled and distributed as library in binary format. On Unix systems it is in Standard C Library (libc)

Comment: So,all the related cpp/c files would have been pre compiled right!!, plz give me a clarification

Comment: Thnk u, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

`string.cpp`

^Well, that's the only answer!

Comment: are you sure it is not `string.cc` :P

Comment: Obviously I am not :P :P :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/correct-c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp

Comment: @Nishant ... or at least `string.c`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it out with `man string`, in which you could find it is a part of **Standard C Library**, as known as the `libc` library.

Comment: Thnku, So u mean for all standard functions, it refers to libc library during linking process

Comment: It's true in some situation. those standard function will be linked during the program starting.

Comment: Thnk u, How does it know that for String functions it has to link with String library file, for math functions to link with math file, Is it based(Decided) on header file?