# mt19937 is not a member of std possible makefile issue

Tags: makefile, g++

In my program I use std::mt19937 to generate random numbers. On two systems (latest windows and ubuntu) the program compiles fine. But, on a third unknown system (using make) I get the error message:
" 'mt19937' is not a member of 'std' "

I am assuming the makefile isn't written correctly. I am new to makefiles and not sure where to start. Do I need to enforce c++11? How would I do so?

```
all:

%.o: %.cc
    g++ -c -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic $<

library-objects = \
    BigUnsigned.o \
    BigInteger.o \
    BigIntegerAlgorithms.o \
    BigUnsignedInABase.o \
    BigIntegerUtils.o \

library-headers = \
    NumberlikeArray.hh \
    BigUnsigned.hh \
    BigInteger.hh \
    BigIntegerAlgorithms.hh \
    BigUnsignedInABase.hh \
    BigIntegerLibrary.hh \

library: $(library-objects)

$(library-objects): $(library-headers)

# Components of the program.
program = rsa435
program-objects = rsa435.o

$(program-objects) : $(library-headers)

$(program) : $(program-objects) $(library-objects)
    g++ $^ -o $@

clean :
    rm -f $(library-objects) $(testsuite-cleanfiles) $(program-objects) $(program)

all : library $(program)
```

EDIT: It might be worth mentioning that I have both cc files and cpp files. Maybe this is causing an issue as well?

Comment: can you provide the name of this "Unknown system" ?

Comment: I honestly don't know but I'd guess it's a mac.

Comment: add `-std=c++11` to your g++ line

Comment: The one at the top or bottom?

Comment: Definitely the top one (that's the compilation stage).  Not sure about the bottom one (that's the link stage).  Try both unless you get an error.

Comment: cc and cpp are both extensions for files containing C++ source code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1545080/1025391

Comment: Richard Critten means:    g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic $<

Comment: I always recommend setting the compiler variable `$CXX` to `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`, since these affect both compilation *and* linking. Use that variable in your Makefile rather than hard coding options. Don't use the system `g++` (although I think it's a `clang` wrapper with an older std library these days). Install a Macport or Homebrew `gcc` for OS X if you want to use `g++`.

Comment: @BrettHale let the default `CXX` is better and don't add option directly to `CXX` but in `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: @Stargateur - no, it isn't. Because $CXXFLAGS is not picked up by the linker. Dialect options properly belong in $CXX.

Comment: @BrettHale Again I disagree, linker flag generally belong in `LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying is that it knows about the "std" namespace but there is no "mt19937" defined in that namespace.

Add "-std=c++11" to your g++ command line because mt19937 wasn't defined until C++11.

(Credit: this was originally posted by Richard Critten as a comment to the question.)

Also, you might need to add this header file:

```
#include <random>
```

Answer (score 2):

"-std=c++11" is not enough , add `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`